# Parameter not being passed with SqlCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that has been working just fine, but I recently added three new params to it:

```
**@HasObits**, **@AlternateName**, and **@Notes**.

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_InsertNewRecord 
(
@CountryID int, 
@StateID int, 
@CountyID int, 
@RecordsOnline bit = 0, 
**@HasObits bit = 0,**
@Name varchar(100), 
**@AlternateName varchar(100) = null,**
@Address varchar(50) = null,
@Address2 varchar(50) = null,
@City varchar(50) = null,
@ZipCode varchar(10) = null,
@Phone char(10) = null,
@Fax char(10) = null,
@Email varchar(50) = null,
@Website varchar(100) = null,
@SearchURI varchar(150) = null, 
**@Notes text = null,** 
@AddedBy uniqueidentifier = null
)

AS 

BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON 

INSERT INTO MyTable (CountryID, StateID, CountyID, RecordsOnline, HasObituaries, [Name], AlternateName, [Address], Address2, City, ZipCode, Phone, Fax, Email, Website, SearchURI, Notes, AddedBy)
    VALUES (@CountryID, @StateID, @CountyID, @RecordsOnline, @HasObits, @Name, @AlternateName, @Address, @Address2, @City, @ZipCode, @Phone, @Fax, @Email, @Website, @SearchURI, @Notes, @AddedBy)

END
GO
```

This code is being called by my data access layer in this method:

```
public void Insert(Company company)
    {
        // create connection
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);

        // create command
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(COMPANY_INSERT, conn);
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        // init command params
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CountryID", company.CountryID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("StateID", company.StateID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CountyID", company.CountyID);
        **cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("HasObituaries", company.HasObituaries);**
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", company.Name);
        **cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("AlternateName", (string.IsNullOrEmpty(company.AlternateName)) ? null : company.AlternateName);**
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Address", (company.Address.Length == 0) ? null : company.Address);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("City", (company.City.Length == 0) ? null : company.City);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ZipCode", (company.ZipCode.Length == 0) ? null : company.ZipCode);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Phone", (company.Phone.Length == 0) ? null : company.Phone);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Fax", (company.Fax.Length == 0) ? null : company.Fax);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Website", (company.Website.Length == 0) ? null : company.Website);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("SearchURI", (company.SearchURI.Length == 0) ? null : company.SearchURI);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("AddedBy", (company.AddedBy == Guid.Empty) ? null : company.AddedBy.ToString());
        **cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Notes", company.Notes);**

        using (conn)
        {
            conn.Open();

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

This same method has been working just fine, until I added the three new params. Now when this method runs it keeps giving me the error: **"@HasObits is not a parameter for procedure sp_InsertNewRecord"**  If I comment that line out, it says the same error only with @AlternateName, then I comment that out and it says the same thing about @Notes, so I comment that out and then it inserts the record successfully.

If I had to guess, I would say that the SqlCommand is not registering the param for some reason. I can run the following SQL command in SQL Server 2008 and it works exactly how I expect:

```
exec sp_InsertNewRecord @CountryID = 1, @StateID = 13, @CountyID = 1, @Name = 'TESTING', @HasObits = 1, @Notes = 'testing notes', @AlternateName = 'alternate name'
```

I'm at a loss at this point. I've never had a problem like this and have spent about 5 hours now trying to find an answer to this, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

The DataTypes for the params being passed in (company.HasObits is a bool, company.AlternateName is a string, and company.Notes is a string).

Thank you in advance for your help!  I'm very very frustrated by this and hoping someone can shed some light on this.

Comment: Have you noted that in your C# code you're naming the parameter as `HasObituaries` rather than `HasObits` as in the stored procedure? Also, could you include the text of the string `COMPANY_INSERT` ?

Comment: Check that you are running the program against the correct database, not one that has the old version of the stored procedure

Comment: Please post the design of your table.And try dropping and recreating the table.Sometimes closing ur SSMS and opening again solves such problems because it sometimes doesn't recognize it

Comment: Some notes: you are using `null` in many places, which (due to how SqlParameter works) should probably be `DBNull.Value`. Also, **personally**, I would argue that there's a big difference between an empty string (`""`) and `null`, and that maybe if `Address` is null, pass `DBNull.Value`, but otherwise: pass the empty string.

Comment: have you tried by clearing you soltuion ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was down to the hosting company moving database servers as I was testing the application and it was no longer pointing to the correct database anymore.

All the code was/is correct (which makes me feel better), but it was just pointing to the wrong db server. I got an email about 5 hours later from the company telling me it was switched and that I need to update any references to the old server.

Answer (score 1):

Your SP has a parameter = @HasObits but your SqlCommand is adding the paramater as HasObituaries.

```
    **cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("HasObituaries", company.HasObituaries);**
```

That could be a source of one of the problems.

Comment: This was a mistake on my part while I was writing my question. I had to change some of the code to hide some of the details of the project. The correct param name is HasObituaries and this is consistant throughout the code and in the stored proc, but I must have missed it when posting my question. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you add

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("HasObituaries", company.HasObituaries);
```

But in your store your parameter is @HasObits.

Change code in this way:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("HasObits", company.HasObituaries);
```

Comment: This was a mistake on my part while I was writing my question. I had to change some of the code to hide some of the details of the project. The correct param name is HasObituaries and this is consistant throughout the code and in the stored proc, but I must have missed it when posting my question.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have the default value for these parameters, you need to add them to `cmd.Parameters` collection. (You can assign `DBNull.Value`).

Answer (score 0):

Settle upon one name; use either HasObits or HasObituaries. Then update the code, stored procedure and column names to all match.